# Change Image Size with Its Resized Size Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Originally the image size is 2000 * 2000. However, it does not fit my window screen. Only the top left of the image can be seen. So I resulted to resizing the image through canvas. How can I set its new dimensions as the image size before I crop it? Jcrop still displays the original image size

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have to resize or crop your image.  just set the width to say 50vw

```css
img{
width:50vw;}
```

```html
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/2000'>
```

Comment: But i still need to crop it. The function is to resized the image or compress it to 1024 * 1024 instead of 2000*2000, then crop a specific area from that resized image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta viewport tag in the head, then use a little smaller size for the image:

Html:

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
```

Css:

```
  img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  }
```